# In a no-slip ideal Atwood's machine (string mass is negligible), does tension or $mg$ affect the torque?

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, torque, string, textbook-erratum

The conditions in this case are: string mass is negligible; string DOES NOT slip on pulley; the pulley's bearings are assumed to be frictionless.
I understand that tension is the force that creates the torque when the string does not slip on the pulley. Although it is a fact that tension is not equal mg, my textbook claims that mg is the force that creates torque instead of the tension.[image] From my understanding, the torques should be torque(g1)=Tension1*R      and   Torque(g2)=Tension2*R   where Tension1 is not equal to Tension2. What is the correct interpretation in this case?
Here is the whole context of the problem for those interested: [image]

Comment: Is the pulley massless?  If not, it will have a moment of inertia.  The solution method will differ a bit, depending on whether the pulley has mass or not.

Comment: Please give details of the textbook.

Comment: sorry for not clarrifying, but the pulley has mass

Comment: the textbook is called "Physics for Scientists and Engineers (6th Edition)"

Comment: Who are the Authors?

Comment: authors are: Paul A. Tipler and Gene Mosca

Comment: You have selected a very narrow part of the text. The context in which this appears may explain why the authors have not included acceleration. Can you post more of the text which appears immediately before this? Then we can see the context.

Comment: @Pranadals, I teach out of the same book.  Are you having a problem interpreting the author's solution to this example problem?  In effect, the solution for torque depends on free body diagrams, and Newton's 2nd law, for each block and the pulley.  The three equations must be worked in order to eliminate tension from the problem, via some form of substitution.

Comment: Oops, I misspelled the poster's name.  @Prandals, see my comment from 20 minutes previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You you and the textbook are both correct.

The textbook is taking an alternative approach which considers only external forces and ignores the tensions in the string, which are internal forces. In this approach the linear momentum of the masses is counted as orbital angular momentum, so that the whole problem can be tackled using the rotational equation of motion $\tau=I\alpha$, instead of splitting the problem into separate but connected rotational and translational motions.

*(I notice that the heading is "Atwood's Machine Revisited" - which suggests to me that (i) the solution using the tensions in the string was done previously , and (ii) this chapter deals with the equation torque = rate of change of angular momentum.)*

The tensions in the strings depends not only on the masses but also their common acceleration $a$.

$T_1=m_1(g-a)$
$T_2=m_2(g+a)$
The **torque on the disk** is
$(T_1-T_2)R=[(m_1-m_2)g-(m_1+m_2)a]R$.

However, the **torque on the whole system** is $(m_1-m_2)gR$. This torque acts on the masses, increasing their orbital angular momentum, as well as increasing the spin angular momentum of the disk.

Comment: so the textbook is low-key wrong?

Comment: "low-key" is just a little colloquial slang popular to the younger generations.

Comment: I have added the context of the problem as requested. Hopefully this sheds more light on the textbook's error?

Comment: Oh so in essence, my interpretation is only looking at the torque of the disk.

Comment: The textbook is not in error.

Comment: Yes, you are only looking at torque on the disk. Tipler is looking at torque on the whole system, including the hanging masses.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the clarification. I really appreciate it.